# Can I produce commercial code with Visual studio express editions?

Tags: visual-studio, licensing

Can I use Visual C# express to produce commercial applications? And are there any other licensing issues.

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, you can. From the [product information page](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/faq/default.aspx):

> Visual Studio Express products are available at no charge and may be used for commercial, production usage subject to the license terms provided with each product. For example, you can use Express for Windows to create apps that you can then submit for sale in the Windows Store.

As for "other licensing issues" - you should probably download it and then review the EULA to see whether there's anything *you* deem to be an issue.

Comment: Is this just for Visual C# or Visual C++ and other languages too?

Comment: @Ayxan: I would suggest reading the up-to-date product information pages.

Comment: The link you provided is now dead

Comment: @Ayxan: Well so is Visual Studio Express, so I wouldn't expect *that* product to be relevant. But you should find the product information page for the actual product you're interested in. [The VS comparison page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/) is probably a good starting point.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the link. As I understand, it is fine to use VS for commercial development for Individual Developers and Non-enterprise™ organizations

Comment: @Ayxan: Looks like it, but I'm not a lawyer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use express editions of Visual Studio and SQL Server to produce both personal and commercial code.

The limitations are mostly technical, what features are removed/disabled. If I remember correctly, SQL Express will give you a limitation of max 4 GB per database. I'm however not aware of any limitations VS Express has for the functionality it offers.

Comment: SQL Express have a limitation of 10 GB for the entire database, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 7):

I found the following in the [Visual Studio 2012 and MSDN Licensing White Paper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350) (emphasis mine):

> "A number of free development tools are also available, including Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8, Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web, Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop, and Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone 8.  These tools provide a subset of the functionality available in Visual Studio Professional 2012 and are specific to writing applications targeting these platforms. Each of these Visual Studio Express 2012 products is licensed per user and subject to the use terms included with the product.  **Visual Studio Express can be used to build production applications.**"

Answer (score 4):

The FAQ link now just points to the product download page, but near the bottom, under `Additional Information` > `Commercial use of Visual Studio Express` for [Visual Studio Express 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx), it states:

> Visual Studio Express products are available at no charge and may be
>   used for commercial, production usage subject to the license terms
>   provided with each product. For example, you can use Express for
>   Windows to create apps that you can then submit for sale in the
>   Windows Store.

As of 3/21/2014 there are 5 products each available for commercial usage, but in different areas:

- Express 2013 for Web
- Express 2013 for Windows
- Express 2013 for Windows Desktop
- Team Foundation Server 2013 Express
- Express 2012 for Windows Phone

You'll want to consult the EULA of the version most applicable to better understand the restrictions.  But I believe those restrictions will be evident in the features of the software.  Meaning I don't think you have to worry about the Windows Desktop version allowing you to write Phone apps that are allowed in the Windows Phone version, it just won't allow you to write them.