# Can I use Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition for commercial use?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, licensing

I know this question has been asked before for earlier versions of Visual Studio Express (2010 and 2008)
However I have not found a **concrete** answer for the same for Visual Studio Express 2012.

I plan to make some small pure C# applications which does not include any other third party libraries.

1. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376472/which-version-of-visual-studio-can-I-use-for-commercial-project) talks about 2010 version and VS 2012 RC but not Visual Studio Express 2012 which was released later on.
2. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420710/can-I-produce-commercial-code-with-visual-studio-express-editions) provides a link to an FAQ that does not exist right now. It gets redirected to a page where you can download the latest VS 2012. After some digging I was able to find an archive of that page [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20101020114424/http://www.microsoft.com/express/Support/Support-faq.aspx). Then again I can't say for sure whether it applies to VS2012 Express. Even after much digging I wasn't able to find any FAQ section for VS2012.
3. Next I tried to dig out the End User License terms of Microsoft products from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/UseTerms/Default.aspx) but I could not find license terms for VS 2012 Express edition.
4. I went through the licensing whitepaper for VS2012 available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350). In Page 26, it states that "Visual Studio Express can be used to build production applications" Dees this mean that we can build apps/programs for commercial purposes?

Comment: If you can't find an answer by consulting your EULA, you have to seek legal assistance or contact Microsoft using http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/pur/phone.aspx. This is a technical forum.

Comment: Ok did you just copy paste that from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/b9175b4d-557e-4547-a40b-3061ecb3ca11/

Comment: I can't seem to find the EULA online,  but presumably if you've downloaded the product it's somewhere in the install?  If so it should make it clear you can use the product for commercial use like all previous versions of Express.

Comment: @James: I haven't downloaded it yet. Guess I will have to do that.

Comment: @Pulimon - Yes and I feel that exactly answers your question. This question may not be fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: In point 1) and 2) I have provided links to questions that have already been asked in StackOverflow. I went ahead because there did not seem to be any comments/answers saying that you should not post such questions. Also the tag named "licensing" actually contains similar questions

Comment: By the looks of this, the answer is yes: https://curah.microsoft.com/2856/can-i-use-visual-studio-2012-express-edition-for-commercial-use

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the looks of [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/1aaf1efc-04df-40b9-9289-f3db0420c206), yes, you can use the Express edition of Visual Studio to develop commercial applications.